# How to restrict term view page for respective user roles programatically? is it possible?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I tried to using hook_menu_alter but it doesn't work. It doesn't call page callback function.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_taxonomy_term_page';
}

function mymodule_taxonomy_term_page($term) {
    echo "hello"; die;
}
```

Comment: Check your spelling

Comment: My bad. But still it is not working.

Comment: Was the typo present in the module, or did you just make a typo when copying the code in the question?

Comment: If you just made a typo when copying the code in the question, how do you check your code is not working? Which user account do you use to test it?

Comment: The typo it was in question, Its not working.

Comment: But later I used hook_taxonomy_term_view and added my code. It is working with hook_taxonomy_term_view.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand... You can use a `hook_preprocess_page` and `global $user` to determine the page the user is viewing, and the roles the current user has, and then do a redirect or whatever if they aren't allowed.... Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  $current_path = current_path();
  $url_components = parse_url($current_path);
  $protected_taxonomy_term = "whatever_taxonomy_term_you_want";
  if (strpos($url_components['path'], $protected_taxonomy_term) !== FALSE) {
    // User is on the path
    global $user;
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    // Change to whatever role you want...
    $allowed_role = "authenticated user";
    if (in_array($allowed_role, $user_roles)) {
      drupal_set_message("USER IS ALLOWED ACCESS");
    }
    else {
      // User not allowed, Redirect user to another page..
      drupal_goto("<front>");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, This solution wont work, page is going into infinite loop.

Comment: I tested my specific code, and it was working for me. Of course, I could imagine you've modified it significantly. If the drupal_goto() logic was redirecting to a page that triggers this logic, than I can see why you would have an infinite loop problem. Perhaps you can update your question with the current version of your code to take a closer look?